# This Sourcecode Doesn't work for Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, firefox

What is the problem with this source code in relation to Firefox.

This source code works perfectly when I'm using Chrome and IE but not for Firefox?

I can't find the bug or error in this code.

The functionality is used from this website http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/

This problem occur in two seperated computer, one with win 7 and the second one is Win8

Thanks!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <script src="C:/Users/xxxxxxxx/Desktop/test/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script> 


        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("p").click(function(){
                $(this).hide();
            });
        });
        </script>


    </head>
<body>

<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/oyuhc79g/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery in same folder.

> c:/.../mySite/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js
>   c:/.../mySite/index.html

so.

```
<!--this is index.html-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script> 
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("p").click(function(){
                $(this).hide();
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

`<script src="C:/Users/xxxxxxxx/Desktop/test/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>` that's your issue. Only some browsers are able to view other files on the filesystem than the one they're looking at; so most web development is performed on a locally-hosted server.

Thankfully, it's pretty easy to get JQuery from Google, and that should work correctly anywhere.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're probably more right than me! I also did not know this information.

Comment: It works well when I use <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: How do you set up a  'locally-hosted server'?

Comment: I admit it's a little more complicated than it should be; you need a simple "web server", a program that accepts HTTP connections and returns requested files. I'm testing my own site using "XAMPP"; that might be a bit heavyweight for you, so you could try installing Python and following this article: http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2012/04/08/simple-http-server-for-local-testing/